# Theoretical doubts about changing a parent node and the effect to its children

Tags: git

As you probably guess I'm a beginner with Git. My questions:

- If you delete a parent node all his children will be deleted too?
- If you modify a parent node his children also will change?

Thank you for your help :)

Carlos

Comment: By node, you probably mean commit? Also, a good start would be (since git is so easy), just fire up a new local repository (in some temp directory), make a few commits, change one and see what happens to the others.

Comment: Hi. I'm seeing the way Git works like a graph (as this tutorial sugest: http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/graph-theory/reachability.html)
A node would be a branch. A parent branch could have children branches.
I have been performing tests with git (egit in particular), and I have these doubts unclear.
And thank you for your answer!
Carlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your comment, where the git term for what you call a node is "branch", the answers are no and no

Going by Shahbaz's thought (which was also mine, commits actually being nodes in the commit history graph), the answers are still no.

You can't actually change commits.  You can change which commit a reference (like a branch or tag name) *refers to*.  That's what the commit and rebase and merge and all the rest do: they add new commits to the graph and usually make your current branch's name refer to that latest.  The older commits are still there, with all their structure intact.  After about three months they'll be subject to garbage collection if nothing refers to them -- but in your scenario the child branches still refer to what they always did, so their histories remain, unchanged.

Comment: Reading your answer I realized I understand Git worse than I thought. Please could you recommend some tutorial about what is happening when you create-delete-modify a branch? I read some of them (quick way, that's true) and I have everything unclear...
And thank you for answering.., I'm deleting more relaxed :P

Comment: Yes. The [gitcore tutorial](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitcore-tutorial.html) will show you exactly what's going on in there, and don't be afraid of it: it's simple.  Really.  To get a sense of exactly how simple git is, do `git init; rm -rf .git/hooks; find .git -type f` and look at the contents of those files (what's in .git/hooks is entirely samples).  Then, as you go through that tutorial, do the finds again and you can see exactly how brutally obvious what it's doing really is.

Comment: Thank you jthill, but don't forget that everything is easy once you understand it ;)

On the other hand, this diagram is helping me a lot to understand where a command affect to: http://robotics.usc.edu/~ampereir/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/GitDataTransportCommands-1024x922.png
But I'm still confused: I deleted a branch (and it does not appear in Github anymore), but I still can recover it from "Remote Tracking." If I understood you correctly, it is because the branch is still at github (and it will be actually deleted after 3 month more or less).

Comment: @chelder, you should know that branches are not just identified by name, but also by the repository they belong to. So `master` on your local repository is a different branch from `origin/master` which is a branch on the `origin` repository. If you delete a branch on your local repo, the branch in other repositories (even if they have the same name) are intact. If you need to delete a branch from a remote repository, see [here](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/02/push-and-delete-branches.html). The command is `git push origin :branch` which simply means push "nothing" to that branch.